# getting returned results after running .BAT file

Tags: batch-file, dos

when i run a .BAT file, it displays a message but immediately closes the window

how i can i force it to keep the window open so that i can see the message reeturned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to conclude the batch file with the

```
PAUSE
```

command.

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap it another batch file that calls the original and then pauses:

```
FOO.BAT
PAUSE
```

This also works for read-only batch files and compiled executables.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to execute this bat file from an already opened command prompt (shortcut: **Windows Key + R**, type `cmd`, press ENTER)